# What is the classic triangle problem as a testing idea (Gruenberger) taken from Richard Hamming (1972)

Tags: testing, history

I try to read up on the history of testing and I found an entry that I am having problems researching online. Googeling for Triangle Problems results in geometry hits.

I found an entry on a [website](http://www.testingreferences.com/testinghistory.php).

> 1973 - Triangle problem (Gruenberger) - In his paper Program Testing: the Historical Perspective - based on the talk held during the Chapel Hill Symposium - Fred Gruenberger introduces the classic triangle problem as a testing idea. Gruenberger takes the problem from the book Computers and Society by Richard Hamming (1972).

What is meant by that? I can not find an online resource for this.

Comment: May be "quality-time-cost" triangle?

Comment: The book seems to be available second-hand on Amazon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to "Software Testing: A Craftsman’s Approach, Fourth Edition" by Paul C. Jorgensen (which I found on books.google.com), the triangle problem is simply this: A program which accepts three numbers as input taken to be sides of a triangle, and then as output classifies them, e.g. Equilateral, Scalene, NotATriangle, etc.

The point of the "Triangle Problem" is to be a conversation piece about what may impair communication or understanding between customers, developers, and testers.